# How can I run a subclass's implementation of a superclass method without explicitly importing the subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Disclaimer: I realize my half-complete solution is unconventional. If my (mis)use of reuse identifiers offends you, consider this a thought exercise that will never end up in production code. :)

---

### Register

I have a `UICollectionView` with many different classes of cell. All of these cell classes inherit from the same superclass: `MyCollectionViewCell`. In an effort to minimize copypasta, `MyCollectionViewCell` has a class helper method `+reuseIdentifiers` which returns an array of strings, each of which acts as both a reuse identifier and a class name (once passed into `NSClassFromString(...)` of course). Looping over this array, I'm able to register all of my cell subclasses as the Collection View's reusable cells for the correct reuse identifier.

```
for (NSString *reuse in [MyCollectionViewCell reuseIdentifiers]) {
    [self registerClass:NSClassFromString(reuse) forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuse];
}
```

Okay so far?

### Dequeue

The problem makes itself apparent in `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` when I try to set one of my cell's properties with a value. Here are my dequeue lines:

```
MyActivityObject *activity = self.model[indexPath.row];
NSString *reuseId = [MyCollectionViewCell reuseIdentifierForActivity:activity];
MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseId forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If I break at this point I can see that the cell is indeed an instance of the *subclass* of `MyCollectionViewCell`. However, trying to set the value of the cell's `activity` property will only run the implementation in `MyCollectionViewCell`, not the implementation in the subclass!

```
[cell setActivityObject:activity];
```

### Cast

I would love to avoid explicitly casting the cell as the subclass, since the subclasses are numerous. I have tried "casting" the cell with the ambiguous `reuseId`, but this results in a build error "Expected expression":

```
[((NSClassFromString(reuseId) *)cell) setActivityObject:activity];
```

If there's no easy way to do this, I suppose I'll have to write the collection view code more conventionally (ie import all of the cell subclasses, let the collection view decide which class to use when, etc). Again, I just want to avoid copypasta, but maybe I'm asking too much of Objective-C? What do you think?

Comment: If `setActivityObject:` is implemented in the subclass and `[cell setActivityObject:]` is running the superclass version, then `cell` is an instance of the superclass. There's no other explanation. Casting will not change the actual class of the object, nor which method is run in response to a message.

Comment: Drat, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway!